# How to fix slf4j error in WebLogic deploy

Tags: jersey, swagger, jax-rs, weblogic

I'm trying to deploy a REST Service (JAX-RS Jersey + Swagger) in Weblogic Server (without Maven) and I'm getting this error:

weblogic.application.ModuleException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/slf4j/spi/LocationAwareLogger

I have referenced the .jar in the project:
[image]

I've tried adding weblogic.xml and adding:

```
 <prefer-web-inf-classes>true</prefer-web-inf-classes>
```

And

```
<prefer-application-packages>
            <package-name>org.slf4j</package-name> (and org.slf4j.*)
</prefer-application-packages>
```

And

```
<resource-name>org/slf4j/spi/LocationAwareLogger.class</resource-name>
```

But doesn't work :(

Does anyone know what this could be?

Thanks & Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I solved it,
I have been adding the libraries one by one as I needed and in the end I only needed these:
[image]